# What changes were made to the Code of Conduct on May 31, 2023?

Tags: support, status-declined, code-of-conduct

There is no clear delineation of what is new/changed and what is the same among the "updated" code of conduct announced on May 31, 2023. What was changed/added?

Comment: For context: the [MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388860/369403) gathering input before the changes. It would still be nice to have a quick before and after

Comment: The previous CoC is available [via archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20230504144938/https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) if the reference helps, but staff have [previously declined to provide a diff or changelog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1296618) stating that: "Since it's an entire re-write, it's not really doable to create a diff."

Comment: A diff is one thing. A calling out of the changes the site administration intended to make (though the wording of the new COC may result in unintended changes) is something completely different and I think that's what's looked for here.

Comment: Mind you, in the prefect world a code of conduct contains exactly one rule: "Don't be a jerk." The only reason we need more rules is to nail down the definition of "jerk."

Comment: I don't have any information beyond what I quoted. We (community and moderators) both requested (in public and private) for a diff to be provided; that was the response.

Comment: So because they've completely rewritten it, they have "no idea" what the intentions of the new CoC is to cover gaps that the prior one did? Sounds like the left hand has no idea what the right hand is doing. I know that SO staff have a reputation of being disconnected from the community, just they are really taking it to a new level at the moment...

Comment: @ThomA the [MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388860/997587) gives a tiny glimpse into the rationale.

Comment: A complete rewrite can also just be rewording it without actually changing it. The idea of course, is that we all read it again and take it to heart anew rather than waiting for the meeting notes to do the least amount of effort possible.

Comment: Just a note that [Staff member Bella_Blue commented a short-list of what they felt the most notable changes were](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1296614) on the feedback post, which is better than nothing at all. She outlined 3 major points: 1) More in-depth "expectations for users" section 2) More thorough list of "abusive behaviors" 3) Adding the "Misleading information", "Political content", "Disruptive use of tooling", and "Inauthentic usage" policies.

Comment: Skimming over it I found no mention of ChapGPT et al. Does it mean it is ok now to post ai.generated answers??? or did I just not look hard enough?

Comment: @TaW ChatGPT wasn't covered by the old CoC either. It's a separate topic.

Comment: There's nothing explicitly in the CoC saying "No using ChatGPT to write content": Is using it to write questions, answers, comments, chatroom posts or profiles supposed to be covered by [*"Disruptive use of tooling policy"*](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct/disruptive-use), [*"Inauthentic usage policy"*](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct/inauthentic-usage), both, neither or something else? "disruptive" and "harmful" are vague terms requiring (positive and negative) examples.

Comment: I just want to comment the CoC is really good

Comment: It's really frustrating to have read one lengthy piece of legalese which was generally sensible and well intentioned, and which I could fully agree to, to then be presented with another apparently similar (and similarly verbose) document to read through some time later which seems to be about the same thing but is apprently slightly different. We can't let the SE folk turn codes of conduct into things like like click-through licences which we just say we agree to but don't have the time to. Codes of conduct should actually guide us in our conduct not be reduced to yet more legal wiglomeration.

Comment: Just doing some light housekeeping. I will refer you to the comment by Henry Ecker as [we previously stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388860/we-are-updating-our-code-of-conduct-and-we-would-like-your-feedback/388866#comment1296618_388866) that, "Since it's an entire re-write, it's not really doable to create a diff."